# How to backup a large (100gb+) microsoft sql database for occasional "offline" use?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a Microsoft SQL database that's over 100gb currently in service. It's due to be decommissioned but I want to keep the data for occasional use without paying for a Microsoft SQL licence (currently provided as part of a monthly subscription by my server provider). Unfortunately Microsoft SQL express has a size limit that is much lower than my database size. What options do I have for retaining this data for only occasional use by a single user?

Comment: If it is not FOR production use, then you can explore Developer edition. Becareful with what you are doing - you are using the product - so if you use it for any PRODUCTION stuff, you are bound to pay the vendor. Explore Opensource dbs like Postgres or MySQL to fit you needs.

Comment: i think given my explanation of the problem, developer edition is the best course of action. If you write it up as an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 4):

If the primary goal is to save money (i.e. not licensing Standard, let alone Enterprise, edition) you’ll need to be creative and accept a certain amount of inconvenience. Some ideas:

- Purge any data you know you don't need
- Break it up into smaller database that do fit on Express (by date, by table, by subject, whatever fits)
- Export it to an open source system (Postrgres, MySQL)
- Save it in on the cloud (Azure, others), using a plan that best supports infrequent access
- Store it outside of a database, on a per-table basis (ASCII file, Spreadsheet)